# How would I remove a certain amount of text after a string?

Tags: c#

So, let's say there is :

> MinimumPasswordAge = 4

I want to replace the 4, except the 4 will be a random number.

Or, how can i remove 1-2 characters after

> MinimimPasswordAge =

BTW, this is all in a text file.

Comment: `NumValue =` is going to be the fix?

Comment: What do you mean by that? I'm trying to replace the number after NumValue =, except the number will be random and not 4.

Comment: Replace the number with what?

Comment: A different number. Let's just say 30.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many many ways to do this. However, here is a regex example

```
var input = "MinimumPasswordAge = 4";
var result = Regex.Replace(input, @"(?<=MinimumPasswordAge = )\d+", "345");
Console.WriteLine(result);
```

**Output**

```
NumValue = 345
```

[**Full Demo Here**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/ykRoST)

<sub>***Note** :This is assuming you know how to read all the text from the text file, and subsiquently write to one using E.g. `File.ReadAllText` / `File.ReadLines` methods*</sub>

**Updated** from [Eric J](https://stackoverflow.com/users/141172/eric-j)'s worthy comment

Use this pattern for white space tolerance

`(?<=MinimumPasswordAge\s?=\s?)\d+`

Comment: Didn't work for me, do you know why?
Code:
                                    string text = File.ReadAllText("secconfig.cfg");
                                    Console.WriteLine("Reading text..");
                                    text = Regex.Replace(text, @"(?<=MinimumPasswordAge = )\d+", minPassAge);

Comment: That isn't whitespace tolerant is it? I'm not very up on RegEx, but I suspect `NumValue=4` or `NumValue\t=\t4` would fail the test.

Comment: It worked in the demo, not in the code though. Maybe i'm reading the text from the file wrong?

Comment: @EricJ. you are right, i should really make it a little more fault tolerant

Comment: @epikgamrgiy you will have to remember to write it to the file afterwards ?